# Adding Coordinates to Variables

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, coordinates

I am trying to create a program, where you have press on certain coordinates as fast as possible. If anyone here knows minecraft, I have a screenshot of a chest, and am trying to implement, that you have to click on the good items in the chest. That is why I need to acess the chest slot coordinates. Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Chest Simulator")
window.geometry("1920x1080")
window.configure(background='grey')

path = "chest.jpg"

Chest1

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))

panel = tk.Label(window, image = img)

panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")

window.mainloop()
```

If anyone can help me here, thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the tkinter `.bind()` function and then inside that function check whether the coordinates of the click are inside your item bounds.
For the item class, you've to enter the lower left and upper right corner of the items hitbox. After the click, the hititems list is filled with the items on which is clicked. Don't forget to clear it after each run.

```py
class item:
    def __init__(self,startx,starty,endx,endy):
        self.startx=startx
        self.starty=starty
        self.endx=endx
        self.endy=endy
items=[item(),item()...] #add your coordinates inside here
hititems=[]
def click(event):
    global items
    global hititems
    for i in items:
        if i.endy>=event.y>=i.starty and i.endx>=event.x>=i.startx:
            hititems.append(i)
panel.bind("<button1>",click)
```